# Optimization of program used for ProjectEuler problem 11

Tags: c++, optimization

I've been learning to program for quite a bit and it seems that one of the greatest competitions between programmers is how few lines one can do a procedure in. Noticing this trend, I'd like to learn to make my programs a bit tighter, cleaner, and preferring functionality without excess. Here's the code I used to solve ProjectEuler problem 11. It's quite large which kinda worries me when I see code a fourth of its size doing the same thing, hehe.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int array[20][20] = {{8,2,22,97,38,15,0,40,0,75,4,5,7,78,52,12,50,77,91,8},
                        {49,49,99,40,17,81,18,57,60,87,17,40,98,43,69,48,4,56,62,0},
                        {81,49,31,73,55,79,14,29,93,71,40,67,53,88,30,3,49,13,36,65},
                        {52,70,95,23,4,60,11,42,69,24,68,56,1,32,56,71,37,2,36,91},
                        {22,31,16,71,51,67,63,89,41,92,36,54,22,40,40,28,66,33,13,80},
                        {24,47,32,60,99,3,45,2,44,75,33,53,78,36,84,20,35,17,12,50},
                        {32,98,81,28,64,23,67,10,26,38,40,67,59,54,70,66,18,38,64,70},
                        {67,26,20,68,2,62,12,20,95,63,94,39,63,8,40,91,66,49,94,21},
                        {24,55,58,5,66,73,99,26,97,17,78,78,96,83,14,88,34,89,63,72},
                        {21,36,23,9,75,0,76,44,20,45,35,14,0,61,33,97,34,31,33,95},
                        {78,17,53,28,22,75,31,67,15,94,3,80,4,62,16,14,9,53,56,92},
                        {16,39,5,42,96,35,31,47,55,58,88,24,0,17,54,24,36,29,85,57},
                        {86,56,0,48,35,71,89,7,5,44,44,37,44,60,21,58,51,54,17,58},
                        {19,80,81,68,5,94,47,69,28,73,92,13,86,52,17,77,4,89,55,40},
                        {4,52,8,83,97,35,99,16,7,97,57,32,16,26,26,79,33,27,98,66},
                        {88,36,68,87,57,62,20,72,3,46,33,67,46,55,12,32,63,93,53,69},
                        {4,42,16,73,38,25,39,11,24,94,72,18,8,46,29,32,40,62,76,36},
                        {20,69,36,41,72,30,23,88,34,62,99,69,82,67,59,85,74,4,36,16},
                        {20,73,35,29,78,31,90,1,74,31,49,71,48,86,81,16,23,57,5,54},
                        {1,70,54,71,83,51,54,69,16,92,33,48,61,43,52,1,89,19,67,48},
                        };

int s = 0;

int right()
{
    int a = 1;
    int i = 0;
    int n = 0;
    int r = 0;
    int c = 0;

    for(n = 0;n <= 359;n++)
    {
        if(c <= 16)
        {
            for(i = 0;i <= 3;i++)
            {
                //cout << " " << array[r][(c + i)] << " ";
                a *= array[r][(c + i)];
            };
            //cout << a << " ";
            i = 0; c++;
            if(a > s)
            {
                s = a;
                a = 1;
            };
            //cout << s << " " << endl;
            a = 1;
        }else{c = 0; r++;};
    };

    return s;
};

int left()
{
    int a = 1;
    int i = 0;
    int n = 0;
    int r = 0;
    int c = 19;

    for(n = 0;n <= 359;n++)
    {
        if(c >= 3)
        {
            for(i = 0;i <= 3;i++)
            {
                //cout << " " << array[r][(c - i)] << " ";
                a *= array[r][(c - i)];
            };
            //cout << a << " ";
            i = 0; c--;
            if(a > s)
            {
                s = a;
                a = 1;
            };
            //cout << s << " " << endl;
            a = 1;
        }else{c = 19; r++;};
    };

    return s;
};

int down()
{
    int n = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int r = 0;
    int c = 0;
    int a = 1;

    for(n = 0;n <= 356;n++)
    {
        if(c <= 19)
        {
            for(i = 0;i <= 3;i++)
            {
                //cout << " " << array[(r + i)][c] << " ";
                a *= array[(r + i)][c];
            };
            //cout << a << " ";
            i = 0; c++;

            if(a > s)
            {
                s = a;
                a = 1;
            };
            //cout << s << " " << endl;
            a = 1;
        }else{c = 0;
                if(r <= 16){
                    r++;
                    }else{break;};
        };
    };

    return s;
};

int up()
{
    int n = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int r = 19;
    int c = 0;
    int a = 1;

    for(n = 0;n <= 356;n++)
    {
        if(c <= 19)
        {
            for(i = 0;i <= 3;i++)
            {
                //cout << " " << array[(r - i)][c] << " ";
                a *= array[(r - i)][c];
            };
            //cout << a << " ";
            i = 0; c++;

            if(a > s)
            {
                s = a;
                a = 1;
            };
            //cout << s << " " << endl;
            a = 1;
        }else{c = 0;
                if(r >= 3){
                    r--;
                    }else{break;};
        };
    };

    return s;
};

int diag_left_up()
{
    int n = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int r = 19;
    int c = 19;
    int a = 1;

    for(n = 0;n <= 304;n++)
    {
        if(c >= 3 && r >= 3)
        {
            for(i = 0;i <= 3;i++)
            {
                //cout << " " << array[(r - i)][(c - i)] << " ";
                a *= array[(r - i)][(c - i)];
            };
           //cout << a << " ";
            i = 0; c--;

            if(a > s)
            {
                s = a;
                a = 1;
            };
            //cout << s << " " << endl;
            a = 1;
        }else{c = 19;
                if(r >= 3){
                    r--;
                    }else{break;};
        };
    };

    return s;
};

int diag_left_down()
{
    int n = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int r = 0;
    int c = 19;
    int a = 1;

    for(n = 0;n <= 304;n++)
    {
        if(c >= 3 && r <= 16)
        {
            for(i = 0;i <= 3;i++)
            {
                //cout << " " << array[(r + i)][(c - i)] << " ";
                a *= array[(r + i)][(c - i)];
            };
            //cout << a << " ";
            i = 0; c--;

            if(a > s)
            {
                s = a;
                a = 1;
            };
            //cout << s << " " << endl;
            a = 1;
        }else{c = 19;
                if(r <= 16){
                    r++;
                    }else{break;};
        };
    };

    return s;
};

int diag_right_up()
{
    int n = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int r = 19;
    int c = 0;
    int a = 1;

    for(n = 0;n <= 304;n++)
    {
        if(c <= 16 && r >= 3)
        {
            for(i = 0;i <= 3;i++)
            {
                //cout << " " << array[(r - i)][(c + i)] << " ";
                a *= array[(r - i)][(c + i)];
            };
            //cout << a << " ";
            i = 0; c++;

            if(a > s)
            {
                s = a;
                a = 1;
            };
            //cout << s << " " << endl;
            a = 1;
        }else{c = 0;
                if(r >= 3){
                    r--;
                    }else{break;};
        };
    };

    return s;
};

int diag_right_down()
{
    int n = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int r = 0;
    int c = 0;
    int a = 1;

    for(n = 0;n <= 304;n++)
    {
        if(c <= 16 && r <= 16)
        {
            for(i = 0;i <= 3;i++)
            {
                //cout << " " << array[(r + i)][(c + i)] << " ";
                a *= array[(r + i)][(c + i)];
            };
            //cout << a << " ";
            i = 0; c++;

            if(a > s)
            {
                s = a;
                a = 1;
            };
            //cout << s << " " << endl;
            a = 1;
        }else{c = 0;
                if(r <= 16){
                    r++;
                    }else{break;};
        };
    };

    return s;
};

int main()
{
    cout << "Result from right():" << '\t' << right();
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Result from left():" << '\t' << left();
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Result from down():" << '\t' << down();
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Result from up():" << '\t' << up();
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Result from diag_right_up(): " << '\t' << diag_right_up();
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Result from diag_right_down(): " << '\t' << diag_right_down();
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Result from diag_left_up(): " << '\t' << diag_left_up();
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Result from diag_left_down(): " << '\t' << diag_left_down();

    cout << endl << endl << "Greatest result: " << s;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The biggest problem is that you're basically copy-pasting the same code 8 times.

Comment: It's what seemed to be the only way to do it to me at the time. There are slight variations in how the rows and columns have to be manipulated and then how much each direction needs to be limited so it doesn't start generating random values. How would I combine these seemingly different functions?

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I notice is that you've got a lot of functions that do basically the same thing (with some numbers different). I would investigate adding a couple of parameters to that function, so that you can describe the direction you're going. So for example, instead of calling `right()` you might call `traverse(1, 0)` and `traverse(0, -1)` instead of `up()`.

Your `traverse()` function declaration might look like:

```
int traverse(int dx, int dy)
```

with the appropriate changes inside to adapt its behaviour for different values of `dx` and `dy`.

Comment: But wouldn't I still have to make the same number of functions, just using slope  measurements instead? Without specific limits for each direction, random numbers are generated when it counts out of bounds, how would I incorporate that into this one-function solution you have?

Comment: @user: Because you know the size of your array, you can calculate exactly which values will end up going out of bounds for a given direction. E.g., if `dx` is positive , then you'll go out of bounds for starting value `x` if `x+4*dx>=x_dim`; if `dx` is negative, you'll go out of bounds for `x` if `x+4*dx < 0`. The same principle works for `y`.

Comment: Just making sure I understood you correctly as my math background is lacking due to my youth: 'x' is the number I start my operation with that increases per iteration? 'dx' is the slope I'm moving x, so if I were doing a SE diagnol it would be +1? And then I think "x_dim" refers to the maximum amount of spaces that allowed in my array, right?

Comment: I think I mean -1 for slope, whoops

Comment: @user: Actually, for south-east, you mean +1. :) Moving south-east is done by moving south *and* east, so you would have dx set to 1 (moves right, i.e. "east") and dy would also be 1 (moves down, i.e. "south").

Answer (score 0):

Well, for starters, you only need four of those directions: right/left, up/down, right-up/down-left and right-down/up-left. Multiplication is commutative, so it doesn't matter which direction you go from a given pair (if you find "a b c d" in one direction, you'll find "d c b a" in the opposite direction, and you get the same result when multiplying those numbers together).

Secondly, use more descriptive variable names. A variable name like `s` is meaningless; something like `maximum` is better, because that tells you what that variable is for. That doesn't mean you should never ever use a single-character variable name - e.g., using `i` as a for-loop counter is perfectly fine, and if you're dealing with coordinates, `x` and `y` can also be just fine, but when at all possible, you should use a descriptive name to make the code more self-documenting.

Thirdly, you can look into what Greg suggests and refactor your methods to take a direction instead. This would allow you to ditch *all* of the similar methods (and just call that one method 4 times with different parameters to cover all of the necessary directions).

And finally, you may want to be more consistent about your formatting - I know that can be hard to start doing, but it helps you in the long run. To understand what I mean here, take a good look at this snippet, taken from your `down()` method:

```
        if(c <= 19)
        {
            for(i = 0;i <= 3;i++)
            {
                //cout << " " << array[(r + i)][c] << " ";
                a *= array[(r + i)][c];
            };
            //cout << a << " ";
            i = 0; c++;

            if(a > s)
            {
                s = a;
                a = 1;
            };
            //cout << s << " " << endl;
            a = 1;
        }else{c = 0;
                if(r <= 16){
                    r++;
                    }else{break;};
        };
```

Notice how you place a line break before the opening curly bracket of your ifs, but write `}else{` on a single line. Additionally, *inside* the first `else`, you have another if-block where you *don't* place a line break before the curly bracket, and the closing bracket has the same indent level as the block content (`r++;`). This is quite inconsistent, and makes it harder to read.

Comment: Ahhhhh, I see now. Also about your comment on formatting consistency, what do you mean?

Comment: @user: I've updated my post to point out what I'm talking about. Also, one final tip: You don't need a semicolon after a closing brace; `}` is enough. (To be honest, this is the first time I've ever seen anyone place one there.)

Answer (score 0):

```cpp
static void largestProduct11() {
    int[][] arr = {
        {8, 2, 22, 97, 38, 15, 0, 40, 0, 75, 4, 5, 7, 78, 52, 12, 50, 77, 91, 8},
        {49, 49, 99, 40, 17, 81, 18, 57, 60, 87, 17, 40, 98, 43, 69, 48, 4, 56, 
 62, 0},
        {81, 49, 31, 73, 55, 79, 14, 29, 93, 71, 40, 67, 53, 88, 30, 3, 49, 13, 
 36, 65},
        {52, 70, 95, 23, 4, 60, 11, 42, 69, 24, 68, 56, 1, 32, 56, 71, 37, 2, 36, 
 91},
        {22, 31, 16, 71, 51, 67, 63, 89, 41, 92, 36, 54, 22, 40, 40, 28, 66, 33, 
 13, 80},
        {24, 47, 32, 60, 99, 3, 45, 2, 44, 75, 33, 53, 78, 36, 84, 20, 35, 17, 
 12, 50},
        {32, 98, 81, 28, 64, 23, 67, 10, 26, 38, 40, 67, 59, 54, 70, 66, 18, 38, 
 64, 70},
        {67, 26, 20, 68, 2, 62, 12, 20, 95, 63, 94, 39, 63, 8, 40, 91, 66, 49, 94, 
  21},
        {24, 55, 58, 5, 66, 73, 99, 26, 97, 17, 78, 78, 96, 83, 14, 88, 34, 89, 
 63, 72},
        {21, 36, 23, 9, 75, 0, 76, 44, 20, 45, 35, 14, 0, 61, 33, 97, 34, 31, 33, 
  95},
        {78, 17, 53, 28, 22, 75, 31, 67, 15, 94, 3, 80, 4, 62, 16, 14, 9, 53, 56, 
  92},
        {16, 39, 5, 42, 96, 35, 31, 47, 55, 58, 88, 24, 0, 17, 54, 24, 36, 29, 85, 
  57},
        {86, 56, 0, 48, 35, 71, 89, 7, 5, 44, 44, 37, 44, 60, 21, 58, 51, 54, 17, 
 58},
        {19, 80, 81, 68, 5, 94, 47, 69, 28, 73, 92, 13, 86, 52, 17, 77, 4, 89, 55, 
 40},
        {4, 52, 8, 83, 97, 35, 99, 16, 7, 97, 57, 32, 16, 26, 26, 79, 33, 27, 98, 
   66},
        {88, 36, 68, 87, 57, 62, 20, 72, 3, 46, 33, 67, 46, 55, 12, 32, 63, 93, 
  53, 69},
        {4, 42, 16, 73, 38, 25, 39, 11, 24, 94, 72, 18, 8, 46, 29, 32, 40, 62, 76, 
   36},
        {20, 69, 36, 41, 72, 30, 23, 88, 34, 62, 99, 69, 82, 67, 59, 85, 74, 4, 
 36, 16},
        {20, 73, 35, 29, 78, 31, 90, 1, 74, 31, 49, 71, 48, 86, 81, 16, 23, 57, 5, 
  54},
        {1, 70, 54, 71, 83, 51, 54, 69, 16, 92, 33, 48, 61, 43, 52, 1, 89, 19, 67, 
   48}
    };

    /*
     * |A11 A12 A13 *  *  A1N|
     * |A21 A22 A23 *  *  A2N|
     * |A31 A32 A33       A3N|
     *  *                  *
     *  *                  *
     * |An1 A2N A3N *  *  ANN|
     *
     *    */

    String line;
    int[] temp = new int[4];
    int compre = 1;
    int result = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 3; i++) { // optimize:- the condition is true 
       // if the remaining index are at least four therefore  the length should be reduced by 
       // three that means only the first 16 members can can satisfy the condition 
        for (int j = 0; j < arr[0].length - 3; j++) {  
            result = arr[i][j] * arr[i + 1][j + 1] * arr[i + 2][j + 2] * arr[i + 3][j + 3];
            if (compre < result) {
                compre = result;
            }

        }
    }
  //
  System.out.println(compre  + " Right sie test  ");
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 3; i++) {
        line = "{";
        for (int j = arr[0].length - 1; j > 3; j--) {
            result = arr[i][j] * arr[i + 1][j - 1] * arr[i + 2][j - 2] * arr[i + 3][j 
 - 3];
            if (compre < result) {
                compre = result;
            }
        }

    }

    System.out.println(compre + " final result");  // solution= 70600674
   
   }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code only answers can generally be improved by adding some explanation of how and why they work.